# setting up oracle native encryption in web.config file

Tags: c#, encryption, oracle11g, web-config

We need to setup following properties in config file to enable native encryption of oracle

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT = (MD5)
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (AES256)
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = required
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT = required
```

Below is the link where I found out it can be done through config file (search for the above properties in link page e.g. ENCRYPTION_CLIENT)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8164

I was not able to find any good example till now.

Can anyone provide an example or link to see how to enable encryption from config file.

Answer (score 0):

In Configuration section add the below lines.

```
 <configSections>    
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
```

Connection String:

```
  <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server name)(PORT=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service name)));" />
```

Add the below section under runtime section:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>

        <setting name="sqlnet.encryption_types_client" value="aes256" />

        <setting name="sqlnet.encryption_client" value="required" />

      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```